# Moongose schema virtual methods - getter and setters

Tags: mongodb, mongoose-schema

I was working with mongoose in mongodb and encountered virtuals in schema. I was looking for some snippets online for hashing the password and encountered with the following:

why is this._password returned in the get() ?

Actual code:

// virtual field

```
userSchema
  .virtual("password")
  .set(function(password) {
    this._password = password;
    this.salt = uuidv1();
    this.hashed_password = this.encryptPassword(password);
  })
  .get(function() {
    return this._password;
  });

userSchema.methods = {
  authenticate: function(plaintext){
    return this.encryptPassword(plaintext) === this.hashed_password;
  },
  encryptPassword: function(password) {
    if (!password) return "";
    try {
      return crypto // these are crypto methods. Read nodejs crytpo
        .createHmac("sha1", this.salt)
        .update(password)
        .digest("hex");
    } catch (err) {
      return "";
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Because expecting `doc.password === 'foo'`after setting `doc.password = 'foo'` kinda makes sense?

Comment: not quite clear on this one, to be honest!!